# min3D in a live wallpaper service?

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, live-wallpaper, andengine

I have been playing around with the min3D libraries a bit lately learning how to use the openGL functionality of Android (it's been frustrating lol).  I am trying to modify the GLWallpaperService @ https://github.com/markfguerra/GLWallpaperService to work with min3D and I just wind up with a ton of errors since this library was primarily written for use with a standard Activity.

min3D can be found @ http://code.google.com/p/min3d/

has anyone or can anyone give me advice on how or what needs modified in order to use the min3D routines?

Nicholas Gramlich was able to successfully write an extension for AndEngine(which he developed) in order to use his 2D routines for sprite animation and it works pretty much flawlessly, I would like to do the same but with 3D elements.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Joey, I am also facing the same problem, did you find any solution ? If you have any suggestion or solution I would be thankful to you. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at https://code.google.com/p/min3d-live-wallpaper-fork/
Its allow build live wallpaper with min3d easy

Answer (score 0):

Nicholas just uploaded a new AndEngine [OpenGL2 release](http://www.andengine.org/forums/announces/andengine-gles2-pre-release-on-december-23rd-t6097.html). I used it to implement live wallpaper (background + animation, that is based on OpenGL shaders). It`s not 100% stable, but provides acceptable level of quality.